# using jquery plugin in backbone with requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I'm trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin in a backbone application with requirejs, and I think I must not quite be understanding how requirej and backbone interact. I've read various things, so I want to make sure I get this working using the project structure I've set up, which I believe is fairly common. Here's my app:

I load requirejs and pass in the main js file:

```
<script src="/assets/js/bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/assets/js/app/main"></script>
```

In main.js I load in all the paths for backbone:

```
    require.config({
      paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        touchswipe: '../bower_components/jquery-touchswipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min',
        templates: 'templates'
      }
    });

    require([
      'app',
    ], function(App){
      App.initialize();
    });

In app.js, I just initialize my router, and in router.js, I initialize my views:

    app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (actions) {
            var homeView = new HomeView();
            homeView.render();
        });

In my view, I need to be able to figure out how to use the plugin. I can tell the source has loaded, but I can't call events as documented.
```

Here's a sample view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/products/productsItemsTemplate.html',
  'collections/products/ProductsItemsCollection',
  'imagesloaded',
  'touchswipe'

], function($, _, Backbone,productsItemsTemplate,ProductsItemsCollection,imagesloaded,touchswipe){
imageLoader: imagesLoaded, //this plugin worked by defining it again here, but this feels like the wrong way to do things, and also, it didn't rely on a dom object in order to work, which i feel might be a problem with touchSwipe

touchSwipe: touchswipe,

el: $(".products-items-container"),

events : {

},

initialize: function(){
  $(".product-items-container").swipe( { //doesn't seem to work, but doesn't throw errors either
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
      console.log(direction);
    },
     threshold:0
  });

},
```

Note my comments for the imagesloaded plugin, which I got to work (though I think through a weird way).

Can anybody clear things up? Using these plugins seems so easy in standard javascript, but backbone is really throwing me off.

Comment: make sure the elements are in the DOM when you attach the swipe handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things seems to work fine :

http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/zzhpmhcd/1/

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min",
            "underscore": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min",
            "backbone": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min",
            "text": "https://rawgit.com/requirejs/text/master/text"
    }
});

require(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    var view = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            require(["//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"], function () {
                $("#test").swipe({
                    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
                    swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
                        $(this).text("You swiped " + direction);
                    },
                    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
                    threshold: 0
                });
            });
        }
    });
    new view();
});
```

I prefer to call plugins only when they're required as shown in the above code. It works fine, even if we load them early.

http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/zzhpmhcd/2/

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min",
            "underscore": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min",
            "backbone": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min",
            "text": "https://rawgit.com/requirejs/text/master/text",
            "swipe": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min"
    }
});

require(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "swipe"], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    var view = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            $("#test").swipe({
                //Generic swipe handler for all directions
                swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
                    $(this).text("You swiped " + direction);
                },
                //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
                threshold: 0
            });
        }
    });
    new view();
});
```

Comment: Wow - that worked. I'm not quite sure what I was doing wrong, but if you happen to check this, can you explain why "swipe" is required, but not necessary to be passed into the function() parameter along with jquery, underscore, and backbone?

Comment: jquery, underscore & backbone are AMD compatible & hence, they export a variable, on the other hand swipe is a jQuery plugin, I don't know if it exports something - http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/zzhpmhcd/3/